# str_extract in R: Extract a string not followed by certain characters

Tags: r, regex, lookbehind

I was trying to extract a substring not followed by "NOT" from a string. For exmaple:

if the string looks like "WKA NOT IN", then the substring should be NA
if the string is "WKA abc", then return "WKA".

I tried the str_extract in R with look behind:
`str_extract(pattern = "WKA (<!NOT)", string)`

However, I still got "WKA" from "WKA NOT IN". I can set up rule to return NA by doing something like `!grepl("WKA NOT IN", string)`, but I wonder if there's an easy way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: `(<!NOT)` is not a lookbehind. It is neither a lookahead. You need a **negative lookahead**. `"WKA(?!\\s+NOT)"`

Answer (score 1):

We can create a regex lookaround

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(str1, "WKA(?! NOT)")
#[1] NA    "WKA"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c( "WKA NOT IN", "WKA abc")
```